# Localized Entities Using EF-Code-First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, ef-code-first, code-first

I’m using MVC with CodeFirst to create a multi-lingual website, and I’ve followed this tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) but I’m facing some problems…

I’ll try to explain in details, so sorry for the long question…

Let’s say I have an entity T with the following attributes (Date, Name) where the name attribute should be localized; I’ve built the following entities to represent the entity and its localized versions:

```
public class T
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public int TID { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Localized Properties

    protected T_Locale TWithCurrentLocaleOrCreate
    {
        get
        {
            T_Locale t = this.T_Locales.SingleOrDefault(record => record.LocaleID == Locale.CurrentLocale.LocaleID);
            // If the object is not available with the current locale,
            // create it
            if (t == null)
            {
                t = new T_Locale
                {
                    Locale = Locale.CurrentLocale
                };

                this.T_Locales.Add(t);
            }

            return t;
        }
    }

    protected T_Locale TWithCurrentLocaleOrDefault
    {
        get
        {
            T_Locale t = this.T_Locales.SingleOrDefault(record => record.LocaleID == Locale.CurrentLocale.LocaleID);
            // If the object is not available with the current locale,
            // return it with the default locale
            if (t == null)
            {
                t = this.T_Locales.SingleOrDefault(record => record.LocaleID == Locale.DefaultLocale.LocaleID);
                // If the object is not available with the current locale,
                // return it with any available locale
                if (t == null)
                    t = this.T_Locales.First();
            }

            return t;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TWithCurrentLocaleOrDefault.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            this.TWithCurrentLocaleOrCreate.Name = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<T_Locale> T_Locales { get; set; }

    #endregion
}


public class T_Locale
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int TID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int LocaleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual T T { get; set; }

    public virtual Locale Locale { get; set; }

    #endregion
}


public class Locale
{
    #region Primitive Properties

    public int LocaleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Navigation Properties

    public virtual ICollection<T_Locale> T_Locales { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Current Locale Properties

    protected static string DefaultLocaleName
    {
        get
        {
            return "en";
        }
    }

    private static Locale _DefaultLocale;
    public static Locale DefaultLocale
    {
        get
        {
            DatabaseContext database = new DatabaseContext();
            _DefaultLocale = database.Locales.SingleOrDefault(record => record.Name == Locale.DefaultLocaleName);

            return _DefaultLocale;
        }
    }

    private static Locale _CurrentLocale;
    public static Locale CurrentLocale
    {
        get
        {
            DatabaseContext database = new DatabaseContext();

            if (_CurrentLocale == null)
            {
                // To Avoid the large logic behind for getting the current locale I’m using the default one here…
                _CurrentLocale = Locale.DefaultLocale;
            }

            return _CurrentLocale;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Where T: is the entity I’m interested in, and T_Locale is a localized version of T that contains only the properties that should be localized, and as you may notice that I’ve written a NotMapped attribute in T (Name) to get the current localized version of the property Name… This property should return the Name with current locale, and when calling the setter the value of the Name with current locale should be modified.

I’ve created a controller for T with Razor views and without any further modifications, and when navigating to the create view I’m getting the right view but when clicking the create button I’m having an exception from the method “TWithCurrentLocaleOrDefault” as I’ve noticed it’s getting called from the getter of the Name property before calling the setter… and as there is no localized versions for the just-created T instance, I’m getting the exception from the method.

I don’t know if I’m missing something here, or if I’m using a wrong logic, so could you please explain to me what’s wrong or point me to a good tutorial or sample code for dealing with localization using Mvc.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was that I'm creating multiple Context instances, so I guess I should change the logic that I'm using in accessing currently localized instance of any localized entity (current T_Locale of T), if there is any good logic to deal with such a case please point me to...

Sorry again for the very long question, Any help would be greatly appreciated, and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Griffin localization, because it is very easy to implement and very easy to manage. There is a very good tutorial on code project: [Localization in ASP.NET MVC with Griffin.MvcContrib](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/352583/Localization-in-ASP-NET-MVC-with-Griffin-MvcContri)

Comment: I did read this article, but I didn't get how it may help me store the required localized versions of any localizable entity... I need a database table that contains each entity translations because modifying translations is going to be one of my project's usecases, data translations not views... And I couldn't download the demo the demo's link may be corrupted. but as for the views localization it's very helpful... thank you.